# Is Celery as efficient on a local system as python multiprocessing is?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, celery

I'm having a bit of trouble deciding whatever to use python multiprocessing or celery or pp for my application.

My app is very CPU heavy but currently uses only one cpu so, I need to spread it across all available cpus(which caused me to look at python's multiprocessing library) but I read that this library doesn't scale to other machines if required.  Right now I'm not sure if I'll need more than one server to run my code but I'm thinking of running celery locally and then scaling would only require adding new servers instead of refactoring the code(as it would if I used multiprocessing).

My question: is this logic correct? and is there any negative(performance) with using celery locally(if it turns out a single server with multiple cores can complete my task)? or is it more advised to use multiprocessing and grow out of it into something else later?

Thanks!

p.s. this is for a personal learning project but I would maybe one day like to work as a developer in a firm and want to learn how professionals do it.

Comment: What makes you think that multiple CPUs will help an IO-heavy appliction?  If your application is IO-bound then you need multiple IO channels, not CPUs.

Comment: Opposite sorry wrong word...it is very CPU intensive. Basically it's just math in a large recursion with lots of data inputs. Seemed like a good process to distribute

Comment: Ah - in that case, carry on :)   Do you need fault tolerance - eg, trying to use volunteer computing scattered all over the place - or are you just looking to use computers in a lab or a cluster?

Comment: Dear lostsoul, please update the question: it is cpu intensive, not IO.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have actually never used Celery, but I have used multiprocessing.

Celery seems to have several ways to pass messages (tasks) around, including ways that you should be able to run workers on different machines. So a downside might be that message passing could be slower than with multiprocessing, but on the other hand you could spread the load to other machines.

You are right that multiprocessing can only run on one machine. But on the other hand, communication between the processes can be very fast, for example by using shared memory. Also if you need to process very large amounts of data, you could easily read and write data from and to the local disk, and just pass filenames between the processes.

I don't know how well Celery would deal with task failures. For example, task might never finish running, or might crash, or you might want to have the ability to kill a task if it did not finish in certain time limit. I don't know how hard it would be to add support for that if it is not there.

multiprocessing does not come with fault tolerance out of the box, but you can build that yourself without too much trouble.

Comment: Celery does indeed have more overhead than using multiprocessing.Pool directly, because of the messaging overhead.  Celery deals very well with task failures in any form, it also supports time limits and much, much more.  Celery uses an improved version of the multiprocessing Pool (celery.concurrency.processes.pool.Pool), that supports time limits and fixes many bugs related to running the Pool as a service (i.e. running forever), and bugs related to shutdown.  Some people use Celery's pool version.

Comment: Some links: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#time-limits http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#revoking-tasks  Pool options: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/internals/reference/celery.concurrency.processes.pool.html#celery.concurrency.processes.pool.Pool http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/internals/reference/celery.concurrency.processes.pool.html#celery.concurrency.processes.pool.Pool.apply_async

Comment: You can also distribute work across machines using just multiprocessing, but I wouldn't recommend doing that.  Making it production quality would probably take considerable effort, and Celery does already have a community that is solving these problems.

Comment: And remember in multiprocessing it's tard slower to share than multithreading. So only use when required for CPU intensive tasks.

Answer (score 35):

I just finished a test to decide how much celery adds as overhead over `multiprocessing.Pool` and shared arrays. The test runs the wiener filter on a (292, 353, 1652) uint16 array. Both versions use the same chunking (roughly:divide the 292,353 dimensions by the square root of the number of available cpu's). Two celery versions were tried: one solution sends pickled data the other opens the underlying data file in every worker.

Result: on my 16 core i7 CPU celery takes about 16s, `multiprocessing.Pool` with shared arrays about 15s. I find this difference surprisingly small.

Increasing granularity increases the difference obviously (celery has to pass more messages): celery takes 15 s, `multiprocessing.Pool` takes 12s.

Take into account that celery workers were already running on the host whereas the pool workers are forked at each run. I am not sure how could I start multiprocessing pool at the beginning since I pass the shared arrays in the initializer:

```
with closing(Pool(processes=mp.cpu_count(), initializer=poolinit_gen, initargs=(sourcearrays, resarrays))) as p:
```

and only the resarrays are protected by locking.

Comment: I managed to separate the pool setup from the measurement but that made almost no difference (as expected, fork is cheap).
Trying with another dataset (276, 385, 3821): celery via pickled transfer 38s, multiprocessing.Pool 27s.
Honestly I find celery much more comfortable to work with and it can naturally delegate processing to other machines in case processing time is really longer than transfer time. On a single machine, the performance difference gets noticeable only for large datasets.