# Python: What is the biggest difference between `Celery` lib and `Multiprocessing` lib in respect of parallel programming?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, celery, python-multiprocessing

I think that all tasks that could be done using `celery` can also be done via `multiprocessing` library.

Despite of this, wonder why the one use `celery` instead of `multiprocessing` in Python program or web framework such as `django`, `flask`, etc.

Comment: Celery lets something *else* do the task.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams why `multiprocessing` don't ? It can also spawn children processes and let them do the task

Comment: Sure, but it's still the same script. And if you're running an OS where spawning a child is expensive then you're just slowing things down.

Comment: What about using `Pool` of `multiprocessing` lib?

Comment: according to this answer here [when-is-copy-on-write-invoked-for-python-multiprocessing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38135787/9059420) `Pool` always pickles, so it's expensive.

Comment: `multiprocessing` gives a threading-like interface to managing multiple processes on a single machine. celery is an asynchronous task queue that can manage tasks over multiple machines in a cluster, for example.

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245656/is-celery-as-efficient-on-a-local-system-as-python-multiprocessing-is